# Sublime snippet - wrap selection and replace spaces

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I currently have 2 snippets, one to wrap selection and another to replace spaces with underscore. How can I combine those two?
First snippet:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[ <%=t :${0:$TM_SELECTED_TEXT} %> ]]></content>
</snippet>
```

and second one:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[${SELECTION/\s/_/g}]]></content>
</snippet>
```

I have two key bindings, and I only want to have one.
Thanks

Comment: Or, How to add second regex to first snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with `TM_SELECTED_TEXT`

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[ <%=t :${SELECTION/\s/_/g} %> ]]></content>
</snippet>
```

It's working now. This snippet is useful for rails localization.